# Display hidden content when radio button is checked using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two check-boxes

```
ABC
XYZ
```

when ABC is checked i'm showing abc content div and when XYZ is checked i'm showing xyz content div

everything works great only when i click on ABC and XYZ radio buttons suppose if by default ABC radio button is checked 
abc content div is not displaying only on clicking i'm getting content of it

my requirement is when radio button is checked i should get hidden content of that particular checked radio button not on clicking

can somebody help me out in achieving it

http://jsfiddle.net/Qac6J/497/

**HTML**

```
<form id='group'>
    <div>

        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" class="trigger" data-rel="abc" checked />ABC
        </label>

        <span class="abc content">
            <label>
                <span>I belong to ABC</span>
                <input type="button" value="ABC"/>
            </label>
        </span>

    </div>
    <br>
    <div>

        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" class="trigger" data-rel="xyz"/>XYZ
        </label>

        <span class="xyz content">
            <label>
                <span>I belong to XYZ</span>
                <input type="button" value="XYZ"/>
            </label>
        </span>

    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.content
{
    display: none;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.trigger').change(function() 
{
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).data('rel')).show();
});
```

Comment: How about pure CSS, with some structure change. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Qac6J/498/). **Code: ** _CSS_ `input:checked + span, input:checked + input {
    display: block;
}` _HTML_ `<label>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" class="trigger" data-rel="abc" checked />ABC<span class="abc content">

    <span>I belong to ABC</span>

        <input type="button" value="ABC" />
        </label>`

Comment: Check this fiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/Qac6J/500/ . if u feel OK, use this. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the `rel` value of checked radio thus use [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector

```
$('.trigger').change(function () {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.' + $('.trigger:checked').data('rel')).show();
}).change(); //Show content on page load
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/zt8e40ru/)

Thanks @tushar With some structure change you can achieve it using pure CSS.

You can use `:checked` to select the checked radio button and sibling selector `+` to select the next `span` and `input` siblings and use `display: block;` on them to show.

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + span,
input:checked + input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form id='group'>
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="group1" class="trigger" data-rel="abc" checked />ABC
      <span class="abc content">
        <span>I belong to ABC</span>
      <input type="button" value="ABC" />
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="group1" class="trigger" data-rel="xyz" />XYZ
      <span class="xyz content">
        <span>I belong to XYZ</span>
      <input type="button" value="XYZ" />
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Sjay Welcome  :). Glad to helped.

Answer (score 1):

just Remove `.change();` from your JS

```
$('.trigger').change(function () {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.' + $('.trigger:checked').data('rel')).show();
});
```

[Your updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaurangnil/zt8e40ru/1/)